# Where is radiotimer_capture_cbt defined in this C program?

Tags: c

Looking at line 21 in [radio.c](https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/blob/develop/firmware/openos/bsp/chips/at86rf231/radio.c)

Where is "radiotimer_capture_cbt" structure defined? I am unable to locate it.

I am hoping the C/C++ experts from the community could help me locate the definition of this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here : https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/blob/a1dbfd8a3341ac3a82ffbb610b4d749f44c429d9/firmware/openos/bsp/boards/radiotimer.h

```
typedef void (*radiotimer_compare_cbt)();
```

Just follow the header files

Comment: grep through the sources to find things: `grep -r radiotimer_compare_cbt /path/to/firmware/`

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly in one of the header files:

```
#include "board.h"
#include "radio.h"
#include "at86rf231.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "radiotimer.h"
#include "debugpins.h"
#include "leds.h"
```

Comment: This is not the case.  I have checked all of the above.

Comment: Looking at `radiotimer.c`, it also uses that structure, but includes only `radiotimer.h` and `opensim_proto.h`, so my guess is one of these two headers.

Comment: Do those header files include other header files which could contain the definition?

Comment: I checked opensim_proto.h and radiotimer.h, both do not have the definition.  I have also done a system wide search for "radiotimer_capture_cbt" but still nothing shows where its defined, only where its being used.